# Hyphenate “communicating”: communi-cating or communic-ating?

Tags: american-english, british-english, hyphens, syllables

The online hyphenator https://www.ushuaia.pl/hyphen/?ln=en provides different hyphenations of the word *communicating* depending on the variant of English: according to that program (which needn't be right), you'd hyphenate *communicating* as

- *com•mu•nic•at•ing* in British English and
- *com•mu•ni•cat•ing* in American English.

Is this true or false? If true, why the difference?  If false, how should you hyphenate in AmE and BrE and why?

Answer (score 4):

Neither is correct. The correct way is: *com•mu•ni•ca•ting*.

Hyphenation is used to break up words at syllable boundaries, so the problem is knowing where the syllable boundaries are. The rule is called the *[Maximal Onset Principle](http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/Maximal_Onset_Principle)*.

Syllables are made up of three parts: the *onset*, *nucleus* and *coda*. The nucleus is the vowel part, including diphthongs. The onset is consonants before the nucleus, and the coda is consonants after the nucleus. So in the word "scout", "sc" is the onset, "ou" is the nucleus, and "t" is the coda.

The maximal onset principle states that consonants are grouped in onsets as much as possible, rather than codas. In simpler terms, **put as many consonants at the start of a syllable as you can, rather than the end of the previous syllable**.

In the word "communicating", there's several places where it's not immediately obvious to which syllable the consonants belong, but the maximal onset principle gives one clear answer. For instance, the "n" belongs in the syllable "ni" because it can be part of the onset of the nucleus "i".

This doesn't mean all consonants go to the onset, just the ones that the language allows. Take the word "instruct", for example. Between "i" and "u", there's "nstr". In English, we can't begin a syllable with "nstr", so we look for the longest string of consonants that English does allow in an onset, which is "str". This means "instruct" syllabifies like this: *in•struct*.

As for the "m•m" part of "communication", there's a writing rule that in English we always separate double consonants, even though the sound belongs only to the syllable after the break.

There are other rules for hyphenating writing that cause computerized hyphenators to make mistakes, including attempting to break words at word boundaries within the word. For instance, in the word "newsletter", the maximal onset principle would break it as "new•sletter", which is obviously wrong because it breaks the word "news". The two algorithms that hyphenated "communicating" in the website you used were possibly trying to preserve the words "at" and "cat".

Comment: Thx! Great answer! Btw., are you aware of any (free) online dictionary with manually checked hyphenations?

Comment: :) Most big name dictionaries are reliable, like Merriam-Webster and Cambridge.

Comment: However, I did not see any hyphenation patterns in their online free versions, at least, in the recent decade or so.

Comment: Btw., “com•mu•ni•ca•ting” is exactly how the word would be hyphenated in German. Coincidence?

Comment: @GeekestGeek No coincidence. The maximal onset principle isn't just for English. It is a language universal

Comment: @GeekestGeek This page has hypenation: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/communication

Comment: Thanks! I must have overlooked this one earlier. (Though it mentions AmE only and only the ground form of the verb, it's still helpful.)

Answer (score 2):

Hyphenation is generally not the author's responsibility, but the typesetter's. US typesetters have tended to hyphenate based on the pronunciation of syllables, and in this word would be divided as "com•mu•ni•ca•ting".  British typesetters tend to follow the division of the word into prefixes and suffixes, and look to the etymology of the word.  The "a" of "icating" is part of the Latin verbal ending; the "c" is part of the Latin root.  So dividing into prefixes and suffixes you get "com•munic•at•ing". There is a common rule of splitting double letters when these provide a hyphenation point.

But there is a fair deal of variation in practice, in both the UK and the US.  Readers are pretty tolerant and can deal with reading texts that are hyphenated the "wrong" way.

My advice would be to *avoid hyphenation entirely* when handwriting. Always start new lines at word endings. Allow your software to hyphenate if you are using word processing or typesetting software. I'll note that "hyphenation" is not taught at school, and children would not normally learn hyphenate manually, and would not be expected to do so. They would learn to read hyphenated texts, but this is not a skill that really needs practice.

So what should an English learner do?  Don't worry.  Both hyphenations above are acceptable and readable.  Neither American nor British readers are going to have difficulty reading the word hyphenated in either manner. Computer algorithms for hyphenation are not perfect, but I have yet to see any example when they actually hyphenate a word so incorrectly that it causes difficulty for the reader.

Comment: Funny you say so because, in this context, I turned out to be a typesetter. So, I cannot fall back to “not my responsibility” or “allow my software to hyphenate”. I do have to deal with the potential deficiencies of hyphenation software. Having said that, are you sure that in in BrE the hyphenation is *com•munic•at•ing*, i.e., with uninterrupted *munic*?

Comment: many typesetters will insert additional hyphenation points, there is a bit of an art to it. For what its worth, TeX (in my British English environment) will hyphenate as com-mu-ni-cat-ing. However, do think if you really need to split the word. Will the line be unacceptably loose if you don't?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's worth nothing in my particular case because I use {Xe|Lua|PDF}LaTeX myself, and though the result is often right, it's *not always* right and thus cannot be trusted. Thank you anyway! (Off-topic: I need to split the word in narrow columns (margins and multi-column index), and the column size is not fixed because both the author and the publisher may throw in changes at any time. Therefore, I can neither insert hard line breaks nor prohibit automatic line breaks in the middle of the word.)

Comment: While not *always* right, see my second paragraph:  There is a fair deal of variation in practice, in both the UK and the US. Readers are pretty tolerant and can deal with reading texts that are hyphenated the "wrong" way.  I would let TeX do its thing, and only hyphenate manually if you see it doing something obviously unreadable. British readers have no trouble reading US hyphenated text, and 99.99% of them wouldn't even notice.

Comment: Yes, and problem is with the term *obviously*. In general, a non-native English speaker has no way to tell by himself/herself whether something is obviously unreadable, i.e., without external help, such as dictionaries, grammar books, tools, or educated–native-speaker advice. Surely the more experience a non-native English speaker has, the better the outcome is, but if he/she also uses the Latin alphabet, chances are high that the discrepancy between *obviously unreadable* in his/her native language and *obviously unreadable* in English will wreak havoc.

Comment: See my new last paragraph.  I've never seen an example in which computer hyphenation has actually created difficulty in reading. So learners should simply not worry about this.

Comment: I did see actual examples when bad hyphenation creates a difficulty, though they are rare (I recall only wrongly-broken compound words anyway). Regardless of this, bad hyphenation in a book makes the author and editor look unprofessional in the eyes of some readers. If there is an easy possibility to avoid this (and in case of a single word, e.g., *communicating*, there is one), you should.

Comment: I don't disagree, but this is not for *English Learners*.  It is a matter for professional typesetters.  As I said, hyphenation is not taught at school, nor is it something that native speakers find obvious. I disagree about communicating - both hyphenation before or after the "c" is acceptable, so there is no chance of getting "bad" hyphenation in this particular case.  If a learner has reached a level at which the worst mistake in their essay is hyphenation, then they are not a learner anymore!!

Comment: However I think my answer addresses all the points in the question: "Is there a difference?" -Yes  "Why" - Different typesetting traditions. "How should you hyphenate?" Don't worry - let the software take control.  Latex actually loads different hyphenation patterns when "British" is specified for the babel package.

Comment: I hate to disappoint you, but let me thank you for “then they are not a learner anymore” — because it flatters me, of course, and my English is broken in dozens of other ways.

Answer (score 0):

It changed in the course of the years for British English. According to [*The Oxford spelling dictionary*, Robert Edward Allen, 1986, p. 49](http://archive.org/details/oxfordspellingdi0000alle/page/49/mode/1up), the British-English hyphenation is

> com|mun¦ic|at|ing

A slightly newer [*New Oxford spelling dictionary*, Maurice Waite, 2005, 3rd edition, p. 97](http://archive.org/details/newoxfordspellin0000unse_n6f1/page/96/mode/2up) says

> com|mu¦ni|cat¦ing

The bar | denotes a preferred division point (you can almost always divide there), and the broken bar denotes a secondary division point (e.g. for narrow columns); their exact definitions are stated in the two dictionaries.

Question: What were the reasons for the change? Is any version wrong?

Comment: Hi. If you have a new question, please [ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) it in a separate thread. See [Ask] for more details.

Comment: @Joachim Hi. This is an answer with a question inside. If you have an answer to the question here, please comment. See Figure 1 for more details.

Comment: I'm pointing out that the answer space is not a space to ask questions. Please take the [Tour] to see how this site works.

Comment: @Joachim Same answer.